# WPF - Maximizing borderless window by taking in account the user taskbar

Tags: wpf

I am creating a WPF window with a custom chrome, so I setted `ResizeMode="NoResize"` and `WindowStyle="None"` to implement my own chrome. However, there is an issue while maximizing the borderless window: it takes the whole screen.

I found the following trick to fix part of the issue: 
http://chiafong6799.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/maximizing-a-borderlessno-caption-window/

This successfully restrain the window size to prevent from covering a taskbar. However, if the user have his taskbar positionned at the left or at the top, this won't work, as the window is at position 0,0.

Is there any way to retrieve more accurately the available area, or to query the user taskbar's position so I can position the maximized window accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a quick play around and it seems that setting the `Windows` `Left` and `Top` properties is ignored when setting `WindowState.Maximized` with a borderless form.

One workaround would be to ignore the `WindowState` functions and create your own `Maximize`/`Restore` functions

Rough example.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Rect _restoreLocation;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MaximizeWindow()
    {
        _restoreLocation = new Rect { Width = Width, Height = Height, X = Left, Y = Top };
        System.Windows.Forms.Screen currentScreen;
        currentScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromPoint(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
        Height = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        Width = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        Left = currentScreen.WorkingArea.X;
        Top = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Y;
    }

    private void Restore()
    {
        Height = _restoreLocation.Height;
        Width = _restoreLocation.Width;
        Left = _restoreLocation.X;
        Top = _restoreLocation.Y;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MaximizeWindow();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Restore();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragMove();
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="74.608" Width="171.708" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Max" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Restore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Obviously you will want to clean this code up, but it seems to work wherever the `Taskbar` is located, However you may need to add some logic to get the correct `Left`, `Top` if the users font DPI is larger than 100%

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

 On a side note, since WindowState is ignored, you also need to add som logic to prevent resizing when maximized. 

Since I implemented the resizing manually with hidden thumbs element, this really isn't an issue for me, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is by handling the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` Win32 message. The code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/maximizing-window-_2800_with-windowstyle_3d00_none_2900_-considering-taskbar.aspx) shows how to do that.

Note that there are a few things that I would do differently, such as returning `IntPtr.Zero` instead of (System.IntPtr)0 in WindowProc and making `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` a constant. But that's just coding style changes, and doesn't affect the net result.

Also make sure to pay attention to the update where the `WindowProc` is hooked during the `SourceInitialized` event instead of `OnApplyTemplate`. That's the better place to do it. If you're implementing a class derived from Window, then another option is to override `OnSourceInitialized` to hook the `WindowProc` instead of attaching to the event. That's what I normally do.