# Set margin for maximized window

Tags: c#, wpf

My window has `WindowStyle="None"` and `ResizeMode="CanResize"` so maximizing it covers the taskbar. I have a workaround setting MaxWidth and MaxHeight to WorkArea dimensions before maximizing and it works great when taskbar is down, but when taskbar is on the left side of the screen window has still position 0,0 and is under it.

**I want to offset maximized window's TopLeft to the WorkArea's TopLeft.**
Window has margin property but that does not seem to work.

I tried following but it seems maximized window can not be moved/offset.

```
 private void mywindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
      {
        MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
        MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
        double ScreenXOffset = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.TopLeft.X; 

        mywindow.Left = ScreenXOffset;
        mywindow.Margin = new Thickness(ScreenXOffset,0,0,0);
      }
```

And ideas on a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [MaxHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxheight(v=vs.110).aspx) of the window to [`MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.maximizedprimaryscreenheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
}
```

You might also wish to set the [MaxWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) of the windows as well.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MaxWidth= SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
    this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
}
```

You could also us the DynamicResource for this:

```
<Window
    Width="{DynamicResource 
      {x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidthKey}}"
    Height="{DynamicResource
      {x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeightKey}}"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
   ...
</Window>
```

For the issue of having the taskbar on the left, see [Maximizing borderless window by taking in account the user taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799691/wpf-maximizing-borderless-window-by-taking-in-account-the-user-taskbar)

Comment: You misunderstood, I already had this set up, but the problem is when taskbar is docked left as maximized window will go to 0,0 under the taskbar, while having empty space on the left.

Comment: You might find this link helpful then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799691/wpf-maximizing-borderless-window-by-taking-in-account-the-user-taskbar

Comment: This does not really maximize window. I still have border, I can still move it, and user can drag window to the top edge and it will be truly maximized. Even if I could intercept that message I would still be improvising.